# touch: missing file operand with filename containing hash #

Tags: bash, shell, touch

My system is

```
Kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
```

Touch version is `touch (GNU coreutils) 8.28`

When the following command is given -

```
$ touch #a{1..10}
```

It says -

```
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Using `set -x` (`xtrace`) to see the command that actually runs)

```
$ set -x
$ touch #a{1..10}
+ touch
touch: missing file operand
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
$ touch a{1..10}
+ touch a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10
```

The hash sign `#` at the start of a word makes the rest of the line a comment. You need to quote it:

```
$ touch "#"a{1..10}
+ touch '#a1' '#a2' '#a3' '#a4' '#a5' '#a6' '#a7' '#a8' '#a9' '#a10'
```

Or in Bash, you can use `shopt -u interactive_comments` to disable processing comments altogether.

Comment: How did you use `xtrace` to check the command?

Comment: @blueray, `xtrace` is the longer name for the `-x` option to `set` ([see the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)). The lines starting with `+` are the shell's representation of what it actually ran. (the extra quotes around `'#a1'` etc. are to make the output unambiguous, and valid as shell input, they're not part of the command.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you want to include the `#` in your file names, which for the shell is the "comment" indicator. Therefore, all text behind an *unescaped* `#` gets ignored, and your command complains about a missing operand.

One possible solution is to enclose that part of the filename in quotes, as in

```
~$ touch "#a"{1..10}
```